# How to create a generic completion closure?

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I have the following protocol:

```
protocol RESTAPIprotocol {
    associatedtype T: Object, Decodable
}

extension RESTAPIprotocol {

    func getList(sinceSyncToken: String = "",
                 pageLimit: Int = 100,
                 progress: Moya.ProgressBlock? = nil,
                 completion:@escaping (_ list: [T]?, _ error: AppError?) -> Void) { ... }
```

and object(s):

```
final class RLMOrganization: RLMDefaults {
    typealias T = RLMOrganization
}

final class RLMProject: RLMDefaults {
    typealias T = RLMProject
}

final class RLMLocation: RLMDefaults {
    typealias T = RLMLocation
}
```

wanting to use it like this:

```
class SyncEngine {

    let listCompletionClosure = { (_ list: [T]?, _ error: AppError?) -> Void in  ... }


    func syncOrganizations() {
        // Sync down from server and update our local DB.
        organizationsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: organizationsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletionClosure)
    }
```

But get the error:

[image]

Which sort of makes sense, but don't understand how I can pass along the generic used as part of `RESTAPIprotocol` into a generic closure?

The goal is to try to accomplish the following:

```
func syncOrganizations() {
    organizationsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: organizationsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletionClosure)
}

func syncProjects() {
    projectsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: projectsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletionClosure)
}

func syncLocations() {
    locationsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: locationsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletionClosure)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about change it to"

```
let listCompletionClosure = { (_ list: [RLMOrganization]?, _ error: AppError?) -> Void in  ... }
```

The completion handle requires a concrete type and you have defined `T = RLMOrganization` within the context of the `RLMOrganization` class.

Edit: a closure can’t be generic but a function can:

```
func listCompletion<T: Decodable>(list: [T]?, error: AppError?) {
    // you must cast `list` to a  concrete type
}

func syncOrganizations() {
    organizationsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: organizationsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletion)
}

func syncProjects() {
    projectsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: projectsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletion)
}

func syncLocations() {
    locationsDAL.getList(sinceSyncToken: locationsDAL.getLastSyncToken(), completion: listCompletion)
}
```

Comment: Casting it (eg. `guard let list2 = list as? [RLMOrganization]? else { return }`) creates other issues that requires me to determine the object type.  In which case, is it no different then just using `[AnyObject]?`?  Can I not somehow communicate the object type within the completion call so that a cast is not required?

Comment: That’s the downside of using generic. One way to mitigate is to put the common properties into a protocol and make `T` conform to that